# Non-overlapping nodes in Forced-Directional Graph

Tags: d3.js, nodes

I'd like my graph to not have the nodes overlap (and any other visual/performance improvements would be well welcomed). I have the following code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <style type="text/css">


      .link {
        stroke: #9ecae1;
        fill: none;
        stroke-width: .6px;
      }


      .node circle {
        cursor: pointer;
        stroke: #3182bd;
        stroke-width: .75px;
      }

      .node text {
        display: none;
        font: 12.5px sans-serif;
      }

      .node:hover circle {
        fill: #000;
      }

      .node:hover text {
        display: inline;
      }

      .cell {
        fill: none;
        pointer-events: all;
      }
      #header {
        padding-top: .5em;
        text-align:center;
        font: 25px sans-serif;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="header">

    Readmission Analysis Graph
  </div>
  <svg width="1700" height="1000"></svg>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v1.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      var dropdown = d3.select("#json_sources")

      // d3.select("body").transition()
      //                  .style("background-color","#e6e6e6");
      var colorScale =  d3.scaleOrdinal([
 '#fedd84',
 '#feda7e',
 '#fed779',
 '#fed573',
 '#fed26e',
 '#fecf68',
 '#fecc63',
 '#fec85d',
 '#fec558',
 '#fec253',
 '#febe4e',
 '#feba4a',
 '#feb746',
 '#feb341',
 '#feaf3e',
 '#fdab3a',
 '#fda737',
 '#fda333',
 '#fc9f30',
 '#fb9b2d',
 '#fa9328',
 '#f89025',
 '#f78c23',
 '#f68821',
 '#f4841f',
 '#f2801c',
 '#f07c1a',
 '#ee7918',
 '#ec7517',
 '#ea7115',
 '#e86e13',
 '#e56a11',
 '#e2670f',
 ])
      var toggle = 0;

      var svg = d3.select("svg"),
          width = +svg.attr("width"),
          height = +svg.attr("height"),
          node,
          link;
      // Call zoom for svg container.
      // svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', zoomed));

      svg.append('defs').append('marker')
          .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
              'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
              'refX':13,
              'refY':0,
              'orient':'auto',
              'markerWidth':13,
              'markerHeight':13,
              'xoverflow':'visible'})
          .append('svg:path')
          .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
          .attr('fill', '#999')
          .style('stroke','none');


      // Create form for search (see function below).
      var search = d3.select("body").append('form').attr('onsubmit', 'return false;');

      var box = search.append('input')
      // .attr("id","searchbox")
        .attr('type', 'text')
        .attr('id', 'searchTerm')
        .attr('placeholder', 'Type to search...');

      var button = search.append('input')
        .attr('type', 'button')
        .attr('value', 'Search')
        .on('click', function () { searchNodes(); });


      var formatComma = d3.format(",")

      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
          .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {return d.id;}).distance(30).strength(.9))
          .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
          .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))


      var changedata = function() {
        d3.json("medicare2_nodes_and_edges.json", function (error, graph) {
          if (error) throw error;

          d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()
          update(graph.links, graph.nodes);

      })
    }
    var linkedByIndex = {};

      function update(links, nodes) {

          links.forEach(function(d) {
            linkedByIndex[d.source + ',' + d.target] = d.value;
            // linkedByIndex[d.target + ',' + d.source] = d.value;
          });

          // var container = svg.append('g');

          link = svg.selectAll(".link")
              .data(links)
              .enter()
              .append("line")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .style("pointer-events", "none");
              // .attr('marker-end','url(#arrowhead)')
          //
          link.append("title")
              .text(function (d) {return d.value;});

          //     // Make object of all neighboring nodes.

          edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
              .data(links)
              .enter()
              .append('path')
              .attrs({
                  'class': 'edgepath',
                  'fill-opacity': 0,
                  'stroke-opacity': 0,
                  'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgepath' + i}
              })
              .style("pointer-events", "none");

          edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
              .data(links)
              .enter()
              .append('text')
              .style("pointer-events", "none")
              .attrs({
                  'class': 'edgelabel',
                  'id': function (d, i) {return 'edgelabel' + i},
                  'font-size': 15,
                  'fill': 'red'
              });
          edgelabels.append('textPath')
              .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {return '#edgepath' + i})
              .style("text-anchor", "middle")
              .style("pointer-events", "none")
              .style('opacity',0)
              .attr("startOffset", "66%")
              .text(function (d) {return d.value});
          // edgelabels.append('textPath')
          //     .attr('xlink:href', function (d, i) {return '#edgepath' + i})
          //     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          //     .style("pointer-events", "none")
          //     .attr("startOffset", "75%")
          //     .text(function (d) {return d.value});

            node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .call(d3.drag()
                        .on("start", dragstarted)
                        .on("drag", dragged)
                        //.on("end", dragended)
                );

            node.append("circle")
            .attr('r', function(d) {return (d.UnKnown/d.Known)*6;})
            .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.group);})
            .on('click', function (d, i,c) {
                   if (toggle == 0) {
                     // Ternary operator restyles links and nodes if they are adjacent.
                       d3.selectAll('.link')
                         .style('stroke-opacity', function (l) {
                             return l.target == d || l.source == d ? 1 :0;});
                         d3.selectAll("circle")
                           .transition()
                           .duration(500)
                           .attr('r', function (n) {
                               return neighboring(d, n)
                               ? linkedByIndex[d.id+','+n.id]*100/d.Outgoing < 100
                               ? linkedByIndex[d.id+','+n.id]*100/d.Outgoing:10:(d.UnKnown/d.Known)*6 })
                           .style("fill", function(n) {
                                    return neighboring(d, n) ?  "#66c2ff":'#fd8d3c'; });

                           // .style("fill", function(d) { return "#66c2ff"; });
                         d3.selectAll("textPath")
                           .style('opacity', function (l) {
                               return l.target == d || l.source == d ? 1 :0;
                         });
                         d3.selectAll('.node')
                           .style('opacity', function (n) {
                             return neighboring(d, n) || n == d  ? 1 : 0;
                         });
                         // d3.select(this)
                         //   .attr('r', function (d)  {return (d.UnKnown/d.Known)*15;})
                         //   .style("fill", '#fd8d3c')
                           // .style("opacity",1.0);
                       toggle = 1;
                     }
                   else {
                     // Restore nodes and links to normal opacity.
                     d3.selectAll('.link')
                       .style('stroke-opacity', '0.6');
                     d3.selectAll('.node')
                      .style("opacity",1)
                     d3.selectAll("circle")
                       .attr('r', function (d)  {return (d.UnKnown/d.Known)*6;})
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.group);});
                     d3.selectAll('textPath').style('opacity',0)
                     toggle = 0;
                   }
                 })


         node.append("text")
             .attr("dx","5em")
             .attr("dy", '-2em')
             .style("fill", "#000000")
             .text(function (d) {return d.system});

          node.append("text")
              .attr("dx","5em")
              .attr("dy", '-1.2em')
              .style("fill", "#000000")
              .text(function (d) {return d.name+" : "+formatComma(d.size);});

          node.append("text")
              .attr("dx","5em")
              .attr("dy","-.3em")
              .style("fill", "#000000")
              .text(function (d) {return "Known    : " + d.Known;});

          node.append("text")
              .attr("dx","5em")
              .attr("dy",".6em")
              .style("fill", "#000000")
              .text(function (d) {return "Unkown:"+d.UnKnown;});


          node.append("text")
              .attr("dx","5em")
              .attr("dy","1.45em")
              .style("fill", "#000000")
              .text(function (d) {return "Outgoing: "+d.Outgoing;});

          node.append("text")
              .attr("dx","5em")
              .attr("dy","2.35em")
              .style("fill", "#000000")
              .text(function (d) {return "Incoming: "+d.Incoming;});

          simulation
              .nodes(nodes)
              .on("tick", ticked);

          simulation.force("link")
              .links(links);


      }


      // A function to test if two nodes are neighboring.
      function neighboring(a, b) {
          return linkedByIndex[a.index + ',' + b.index];
      }


      function ticked() {
          link
              .attr("x1", function (d) {return d.source.x;})
              .attr("y1", function (d) {return d.source.y;})
              .attr("x2", function (d) {return d.target.x;})
              .attr("y2", function (d) {return d.target.y;});

          node
          // .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.width, Math.min(width - d.width, d.x)); })
          // .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.height, Math.min(height - heightDelta - d.height, d.y)); })
          .attr("transform", function (d) {return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";});


          edgepaths.attr('d', function (d) {
              return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
          });

          edgelabels.attr('transform', function (d) {
              if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                  var bbox = this.getBBox();

                  rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                  ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                  return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
              }
              else {
                  return 'rotate(0)';
              }
            });


      }


      // Zooming function translates the size of the svg container.
      // function zoomed() {
      //      svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.transform.x + ", " + d3.event.transform.y + ") scale(" + d3.event.transform.k + ")");
      // }

      function dragstarted(d) {
          if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
          d.fx = d.x;
          d.fy = d.y;
      }

      function dragged(d) {
          d.fx = d3.event.x;
          d.fy = d3.event.y;
      }

      // Search for nodes by making all unmatched nodes temporarily transparent.
      function searchNodes() {
            var term = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value;
            var selected = svg.selectAll('.node').filter(function (d, i) {
                return (d.system.toLowerCase().search(term.toLowerCase()) == -1&&d.name.toLowerCase().search(term.toLowerCase()) == -1);
            });
            selected.style('opacity', '0');
            var link = svg.selectAll('.link');
            link.style('stroke-opacity', '0');
            d3.selectAll('.node').transition()
                .duration(4000)
                .style('opacity', '1');
            d3.selectAll('.link').transition().duration(4000).style('stroke-opacity', '0.6');
        }

      dropdown.on("change", changedata)
      changedata()


  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is some dummy data:

```
 {"nodes": [{"id": 0, "name": "ALASKA NATIVE TRIBAL HEALTH CONSORTIUM", "group": 0, "system": "ALASKA NATIVE TRIBAL HEALTH CONSORTIUM", "size": 1828, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.0, "UnKnown": 0.0, "delta": 0.0}, {"id": 1, "name": "ADIRONDACK MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 1, "system": "Adirondack Health", "size": 853, "Outgoing": 4, "Incoming": 1, "Known": 0.161, "UnKnown": 0.165, "delta": 0.972}, {"id": 2, "name": "ALBANY MEDICAL CENTER HOSPITAL", "group": 2, "system": "Albany Medical Center Health System", "size": 10964, "Outgoing": 37, "Incoming": 28, "Known": 0.214, "UnKnown": 0.217, "delta": 0.984}, {"id": 3, "name": "ALBANY MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH CLINICAL CAMPUS", "group": 2, "system": "Albany Medical Center Health System", "size": 1, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.0, "UnKnown": 0.0, "delta": 0.0}, {"id": 4, "name": "ABBOTT NORTHWESTERN HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 12772, "Outgoing": 223, "Incoming": 281, "Known": 0.135, "UnKnown": 0.152, "delta": 0.885}, {"id": 5, "name": "ALLINA HEALTH REGINA HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 534, "Outgoing": 26, "Incoming": 15, "Known": 0.081, "UnKnown": 0.129, "delta": 0.623}, {"id": 6, "name": "ALLINA HEALTH SYSTEM", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 10775, "Outgoing": 175, "Incoming": 160, "Known": 0.139, "UnKnown": 0.156, "delta": 0.896}, {"id": 7, "name": "BUFFALO HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 741, "Outgoing": 17, "Incoming": 14, "Known": 0.061, "UnKnown": 0.084, "delta": 0.726}, {"id": 8, "name": "CAMBRIDGE MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 861, "Outgoing": 52, "Incoming": 39, "Known": 0.087, "UnKnown": 0.148, "delta": 0.591}, {"id": 9, "name": "DISTRICT ONE HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 566, "Outgoing": 20, "Incoming": 12, "Known": 0.129, "UnKnown": 0.164, "delta": 0.785}, {"id": 10, "name": "NEW ULM MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 693, "Outgoing": 19, "Incoming": 12, "Known": 0.124, "UnKnown": 0.152, "delta": 0.819}, {"id": 11, "name": "PHILLIPS EYE INSTITUTE", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 6, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.0, "UnKnown": 0.0, "delta": 0.0}, {"id": 12, "name": "RIVER FALLS AREA HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 448, "Outgoing": 19, "Incoming": 23, "Known": 0.08, "UnKnown": 0.123, "delta": 0.655}, {"id": 13, "name": "ST. FRANCIS REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 2005, "Outgoing": 51, "Incoming": 41, "Known": 0.119, "UnKnown": 0.144, "delta": 0.824}, {"id": 14, "name": "UNITED HOSPITAL", "group": 3, "system": "Allina Health", "size": 8260, "Outgoing": 124, "Incoming": 120, "Known": 0.141, "UnKnown": 0.156, "delta": 0.904}, {"id": 15, "name": "BANNER -- UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER PHOENIX", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 5651, "Outgoing": 204, "Incoming": 187, "Known": 0.138, "UnKnown": 0.174, "delta": 0.793}, {"id": 16, "name": "BANNER -- UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH CAMPUS LLC", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 1238, "Outgoing": 51, "Incoming": 34, "Known": 0.128, "UnKnown": 0.17, "delta": 0.757}, {"id": 17, "name": "BANNER --UNIVERSITY MEDICAL CENTER TUCSON CAMPUS LLC", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 4469, "Outgoing": 55, "Incoming": 59, "Known": 0.181, "UnKnown": 0.194, "delta": 0.936}, {"id": 18, "name": "BANNER BAYWOOD MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 6316, "Outgoing": 162, "Incoming": 181, "Known": 0.102, "UnKnown": 0.128, "delta": 0.799}, {"id": 19, "name": "BANNER BOSWELL MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 5419, "Outgoing": 141, "Incoming": 147, "Known": 0.117, "UnKnown": 0.143, "delta": 0.818}, {"id": 20, "name": "BANNER CASA GRANDE MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 1699, "Outgoing": 41, "Incoming": 32, "Known": 0.131, "UnKnown": 0.155, "delta": 0.844}, {"id": 21, "name": "BANNER CHURCHILL COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 536, "Outgoing": 1, "Incoming": 1, "Known": 0.14, "UnKnown": 0.142, "delta": 0.987}, {"id": 22, "name": "BANNER DEL E WEBB MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 5407, "Outgoing": 119, "Incoming": 133, "Known": 0.107, "UnKnown": 0.129, "delta": 0.829}, {"id": 23, "name": "BANNER DESERT MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 5593, "Outgoing": 181, "Incoming": 145, "Known": 0.148, "UnKnown": 0.181, "delta": 0.821}, {"id": 24, "name": "BANNER ESTRELLA MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 2426, "Outgoing": 78, "Incoming": 62, "Known": 0.131, "UnKnown": 0.163, "delta": 0.803}, {"id": 25, "name": "BANNER FORT COLLINS MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 148, "Outgoing": 5, "Incoming": 3, "Known": 0.054, "UnKnown": 0.088, "delta": 0.615}, {"id": 26, "name": "BANNER GATEWAY MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 2099, "Outgoing": 91, "Incoming": 95, "Known": 0.141, "UnKnown": 0.184, "delta": 0.765}, {"id": 27, "name": "BANNER GOLDFIELD MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 221, "Outgoing": 16, "Incoming": 4, "Known": 0.036, "UnKnown": 0.109, "delta": 0.333}, {"id": 28, "name": "BANNER IRONWOOD MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 585, "Outgoing": 24, "Incoming": 12, "Known": 0.068, "UnKnown": 0.109, "delta": 0.625}, {"id": 29, "name": "BANNER LASSEN MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 340, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.185, "UnKnown": 0.185, "delta": 1.0}, {"id": 30, "name": "BANNER PAYSON MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 773, "Outgoing": 37, "Incoming": 13, "Known": 0.089, "UnKnown": 0.137, "delta": 0.651}, {"id": 31, "name": "BANNER THUNDERBIRD MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 3760, "Outgoing": 119, "Incoming": 132, "Known": 0.135, "UnKnown": 0.167, "delta": 0.81}, {"id": 32, "name": "COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 265, "Outgoing": 4, "Incoming": 2, "Known": 0.143, "UnKnown": 0.158, "delta": 0.905}, {"id": 33, "name": "EAST MORGAN COUNTY HOSPITAL", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 207, "Outgoing": 13, "Incoming": 7, "Known": 0.053, "UnKnown": 0.116, "delta": 0.458}, {"id": 34, "name": "MCKEE MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 913, "Outgoing": 9, "Incoming": 12, "Known": 0.106, "UnKnown": 0.116, "delta": 0.915}, {"id": 35, "name": "NORTH COLORADO MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 3460, "Outgoing": 26, "Incoming": 31, "Known": 0.133, "UnKnown": 0.14, "delta": 0.946}, {"id": 36, "name": "OGALLALA COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 194, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.139, "UnKnown": 0.139, "delta": 1.0}, {"id": 37, "name": "PLATTE COUNTY MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 231, "Outgoing": 0, "Incoming": 0, "Known": 0.182, "UnKnown": 0.182, "delta": 1.0}, {"id": 38, "name": "STERLING REGIONAL MEDCENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 474, "Outgoing": 6, "Incoming": 8, "Known": 0.105, "UnKnown": 0.118, "delta": 0.893}, {"id": 39, "name": "WASHAKIE MEDICAL CENTER", "group": 4, "system": "Banner Health", "size": 250, "Outgoing": 8, "Incoming": 6, "Known": 0.116, "UnKnown": 0.148, "delta": 0.784}], "links": [{"source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 2}, {"source": 1, "target": 186, "value": 1}, {"source": 1, "target": 193, "value": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 1, "value": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 186, "value": 4}, {"source": 2, "target": 53, "value": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 254, "value": 2}, {"source": 2, "target": 63, "value": 7}, {"source": 2, "target": 65, "value": 4}, {"source": 2, "target": 193, "value": 3}, {"source": 2, "target": 244, "value": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 248, "value": 1}, {"source": 2, "target": 66, "value": 9}, {"source": 2, "target": 255, "value": 3}, {"source": 2, "target": 253, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 2, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 5, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 6, "value": 74}, {"source": 4, "target": 7, "value": 3}, {"source": 4, "target": 8, "value": 23}, {"source": 4, "target": 49, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 9, "value": 12}, {"source": 4, "target": 71, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 222, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 10, "value": 12}, {"source": 4, "target": 171, "value": 29}, {"source": 4, "target": 12, "value": 2}, {"source": 4, "target": 75, "value": 1}, {"source": 4, "target": 13, "value": 29}, {"source": 4, "target": 14, "value": 33}, {"source": 5, "target": 4, "value": 1}, {"source": 5, "target": 6, "value": 2}, {"source": 5, "target": 14, "value": 23}, {"source": 6, "target": 4, "value": 90}, {"source": 6, "target": 7, "value": 6}, {"source": 6, "target": 8, "value": 13}, {"source": 6, "target": 171, "value": 37}, {"source": 6, "target": 216, "value": 1}, {"source": 6, "target": 14, "value": 19}, {"source": 7, "target": 4, "value": 7}, {"source": 7, "target": 6, "value": 8}, {"source": 7, "target": 171, "value": 2}, {"source": 8, "target": 4, "value": 27}, {"source": 8, "target": 6, "value": 22}, {"source": 8, "target": 14, "value": 3}, {"source": 9, "target": 4, "value": 16}, {"source": 9, "target": 13, "value": 1}, {"source": 9, "target": 14, "value": 3}, {"source": 10, "target": 4, "value": 18}, {"source": 10, "target": 14, "value": 1}, {"source": 12, "target": 4, "value": 1}, {"source": 12, "target": 14, "value": 18}, {"source": 13, "target": 4, "value": 41}, {"source": 13, "target": 14, "value": 9}, {"source": 14, "target": 4, "value": 47}, {"source": 14, "target": 5, "value": 14}, {"source": 14, "target": 6, "value": 23}, {"source": 14, "target": 8, "value": 3}, {"source": 14, "target": 56, "value": 1}, {"source": 14, "target": 171, "value": 2}, {"source": 14, "target": 172, "value": 1}, {"source": 14, "target": 12, "value": 19}, {"source": 14, "target": 75, "value": 1}, {"source": 14, "target": 77, "value": 1}, {"source": 14, "target": 13, "value": 9}]
```

My actual JSON has 200+ nodes and is very slow. The nodes that aren't connected go out of site off the page (which would be nice to not have as well). The ones that are super connected generally overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [d3.forceCollide](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forceCollide)  to avoid overlapping.

As for the nodes going out, playing a little bit with the forces will help you adjust their behavior, I would recommend read all the forces and what they do [D3 Simulation Forces](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#forces).

I changed your code to this:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) {return d.id;}).distance(100).strength(.9))
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-10))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(radiusFn))
```

With radiusFn being:

```
function radiusFn(d) {
  var r = (d.UnKnown/d.Known)*6;

  if(isNaN(r)) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return r;
  }
}
```

I created this function and used it in every part of your code where you set the node radius, because I got a few "NaN" errors, wich is invalid for a SVG circle radius, you can adjust it to your desired behavior.

Finally, I changed the values for **d3.forceManyBody** to -10, so they don't repel too much.

With those changes, the visualization should look like this:

[image: New look:]